# ASP.Net Dynamic Data IS showing my primary keys for every table when using Entities

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

Using a very run-of-the-mill database, with identity int for primary keys, a Dynamic Data Entities Project (EntityFramework) displays the primary key for view and edit. When using Linq to Sql, the primary key fields are not displayed.

I would like to hide the primary keys and use Entity Framework (VS 2008, .Net 3.5 sp1).
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `ScaffoldColumnAttribute` to not scaffold a column.

You'll need to either customize code generation (easier in EF 4) or use a buddy class for this.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntity_Metadata))]
public partial class MyEntity 
{
}

public class MyEntity_Metadata 
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is a third option; wiring up your own convention based  AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider.   http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/08/dynamic_data_and_custom_metada.html